# Scala - Combinator Parsing, order of alternatives seems to matter

Tags: scala, parsing

I am relatively new to Scala and I'm trying to get a grasp of combinator parsing. So I have some code that parses logical atoms (predicates in first-order logic) like `p(x,y,z)` or `p(x,1,q(a,b,c),z)`. I have this little piece of code:

```
class Logic extends JavaTokenParsers {
    def functor: Parser[Any] = ident
    def term: Parser[Any] = predicate | ident | floatingPointNumber
    def predicate: Parser[Any] = functor~"("~repsep(term,",")~")"  
}
```

`Functor` is the predicate symbol, like `p` in `p(x,y,z)`, `term` is a constant or variable like `1` or `x`, or a `predicate`, and a `predicate` is a compound term like `p(x,y,z)`. This code works fine as is, but has problems if I change the order with which I declare the alternatives in the `term` parser. That is, if I write the `term` parser like

```
def term: Parser[Any] = ident | floatingPointNumber | predicate
```

(`predicate` is the last alternative here, while it was first previously), then it fails parsing "nested" expressions like `p(x,1,q(a,b,c),z)` (while it still works for "flat" expressions like `p(x,y,z)`). Could someone please indicate what I am missing here?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Order Matters

The reason is `A | B` will try to satisfy `A` first and `B` is tried only if `A` fails.

This is different from `|` in regular expressions (or context-free grammars in general).

In this case in `"p(x,1,q(a,b,c),z)"` `p` satisfies `ident` so other alternatives won't be matched (and there is no backtracking).

For this reason, amongst alternatives with clashing prefixes, you can put  the one accepting longer strings first (or the one you know that will result in satisfying more phrases).

### Longest Alternative Matching

Note that you can use `|||` combinator:

```
def term: Parser[Any] = ident ||| floatingPointNumber ||| predicate
```

According to the [Scala docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.2/scala-parser-combinators/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser@|||[U>:T](q0:=>Parsers.this.Parser[U]):Parsers.this.Parser[U]), `|||` is a parser combinator matching alternatives with longest match composition.

Comment: Ok, that's really helpfull and I didn't know about the `|||` combinator. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I'm going assume you try to parse via `logic.parse(logic.term, "p(x,1,q(a,b,c),z)")`.

In fact, the order of alternatives does matter, as the parser will choose the first alternative to match the given input. In your case, `p` matches the `ident` definition. The parser will then return a [ParseResult](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$ParseResult) containing the match (type `Any` in your case) and the rest of the input, which is `(x,1,q(a,b,c),z)` in your case.

Comment: Actually I was trying to parse through the `predicate` parser. But it's ok I get it now. Thanks a lot for your answer